# Ruby: Is a string in a list of values

Tags: ruby, string, compare

Newbie Ruby question:

I'm currently writing:

```
if mystring == "valueA" or mystring == "ValueB" or mystring == "ValueC"
```

is there a neater way of doing this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are two ways:

RegEx:

```
if mystring =~ /^value(A|B|C)$/ # Use /\Avalue(A|B|C)\Z/ here instead 
   # do something               # to escape new lines
end
```

Or, more explicitly,

```
if ['valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC'].include?(mystring)
   # do something
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: In Ruby, you should really reach for anchors \A and \Z unless you're sure the string contains zero newlines.

Answer (score 7):

How 'bout

```
if %w(valueA valueB valueC).include?(mystring)
  # do something
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you'd want to extend this functionality with other match groups, you could also use case:

```
case mystring
when "valueA", "valueB", "valueC" then
 #do_something
when "value1", "value2", "value3" then
 #do_something else
else
 #do_a_third_thing
end
```